# WCF FaultCode MustUnderstand = 1 .net 4.0

Tags: wcf

How do I change my wcf service to be able to accept mustunderstand = 1?
This is a scenario where I have to change the service to be able to accept a request from the client. The client sends mustunderstand =1 in the header.

The service is configured to use basichttpBinding

```
 <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
```

Using soap UI I insert the following username token into the header

```
 <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2684C13EA73A35131015516775308851">
            <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>

         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
```

I can reproduce the issue on soap UI when I insert this token in the wcf service request. This is the error

```
<FaultMsgRec>
  <ErrCode>100</ErrCode>
  <ErrCat>Error</ErrCat>
  <ErrDesc>An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.--&gt; The header 'Security' from the namespace 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' was not understood by the recipient of this message, causing the message to not be processed.  This error typically indicates that the sender of this message has enabled a communication protocol that the receiver cannot process.  Please ensure that the configuration of the client's binding is consistent with the service's binding. </ErrDesc>
</FaultMsgRec>
```

Since I have control over the wcf service I can go and add ValidateMustUnderstand = false in the service behavior.
Just like it is explained in the link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.description.mustunderstandbehavior.validatemustunderstand?view=netframework-4.7.2

Once I add this to the service behavior the error disappears. 
But  I don't want to turn off validation on the header especially if its a username, password. What should I do to allow mustunderstand=1? Am I missing something that the service doesn't automatically process mustunderstand=1 by default. I know there is code to be written on the client in order to sent a 0 in the header.

I am using message contracts in my wcf service not data contract. I understand that for certain properties I can go and add attributes like this link 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.messageheaderattribute.mustunderstand?view=netframework-4.7.2. But I am not adding to any properties. I am just adding it to the first linke in soapenv:mustunderstand=1

Please help!.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this could solve your problem. But you could try to add your header in web.config.

```
  <endpoint address="http://ws-wuxipc-5077:4000/calculator" binding="basicHttpBinding"
  contract="ServiceInterface.ICalculatorService" name="cal">
  <headers>
    <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" >
      <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
        xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>
        </wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">monMonDePasse</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce>sdsdsdlojhfdsdM5Nw==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2019-01-21T6:17:34Z</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </Security>
  </headers>
</endpoint>
```

Or you could add header using code.

```
 using (ChannelFactory<ICalculatorService> ChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ICalculatorService>("cal"))
    {
                        ICalculatorService employeeService = ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
        using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)employeeService))
        {

            System.Xml.XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();


            XmlElement element = document.CreateElement("wsse", "UsernameToken", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");


            XmlElement newChild = null;

            newChild = document.CreateElement("wsse", "Username", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
            newChild.InnerText = "finance";
            element.AppendChild(newChild);

            newChild = document.CreateElement("wsse", "password", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
            newChild.SetAttribute("Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest");
            newChild.InnerText = "387";
            element.AppendChild(newChild);

            MessageHeader messageHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("security", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", element, false); // here is mustunderstood is set to false


            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(messageHeader);

        }

                       Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: I am not trying to modify the client. I am trying to match the service to  be able a request from the client. The client sends mustundertand =1 and I need be able to change the service to be able to accept it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Have you configure your server side correctly?[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878065/wcf-service-with-wshttpbinding-ssl-and-transportwithmessagecredential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878065/wcf-service-with-wshttpbinding-ssl-and-transportwithmessagecredential) , you could also refer to  Microsoft doc to learn how to configure server side  [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-a-user-name-client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-a-user-name-client)